# How to call a python function inside of a command line while application is running?

Tags: python, shell, user-interface

How do i call a function inside my application from the command line while the application is already running.?

I am trying to make a .bat file that opens gui of my application, even though the application is running in the background.

Comment: The command line doesn't work that way. The command will start a new process. That process would have to somehow detect the existing process and communicate with it. This is not an ordinary way to design program UIs, and you would probably need to give a lot more detail on the specific situation to make it make sense.

Comment: You need to use some form of IPC to tell your application to run the function. For example, your application could listen on a socket or file descriptor for the signal to open the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

The shell script cannot communicate directly with a running process.

The simplest and “dirty” way is to make your script polling for some file in a predefined path and execute your code if you create the file.

```
from os.path import exists

while True:

print("Waiting for the creation of the file.")
time.sleep(5)

if exists("path_to_file"):
    run_your_code
```